# Replacement of a group of variables in trigonometric expression

Tags: replacement, trigonometry, rule

I would like to make simplification of trigonometric expressions by using a replacement a group of variables.

Here the equation I have to simplify :

```
   -Cos[γ[1][t] - θ[1][t] - ψ[1][t]] l[f] + 
  m[f] Sin[γ[1][t]] + 
  c[f] Sin[γ[1][t] - θ[1][t]] - 
  h[f] Sin[γ[1][t] - θ[1][t] - ψ[1][t]] + 
  x[P1][
   t] == -Cos[γ[2][t] - θ[2][t] - ψ[2][t]] l[f] + 
  m[f] Sin[γ[2][t]] + 
  c[f] Sin[γ[2][t] - θ[2][t]] - 
  h[f] Sin[γ[2][t] - θ[2][t] - ψ[2][t]] + 
  x[P2][t]
```

For the simplification I also this equation

```
γ[1][t] - θ[1][t] - ψ[1][t] == γ[2][t] - θ[2][t] - ψ[2][t]
```

Consequently, I would like to replace only in the right hand side the group of variables `γ[2][t] - θ[2][t] - ψ[2][t] by γ[1][t] - θ[1][t] - ψ[1][t]`

After simplifications, I would like to obtain this equation :

```
m[f] Sin[γ[1][t]] + c[f] Sin[γ[1][t] - θ[1][t]] + x[P1][t] == 
  m[f] Sin[γ[2][t]] + c[f] Sin[γ[2][t] - θ[2][t]] + x[P2][t]
```

Have you some ideas so to do this replacement `γ[1][t] - θ[1][t] - ψ[1][t] == γ[2][t] - θ[2][t] - ψ[2][t]` in the right hand side of my equation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
FullSimplify[
   -Cos[γ[1][t] - θ[1][t] - ψ[1][t]] l[f] + m[f] Sin[γ[1][t]] + 
   c[f] Sin[γ[1][t] - θ[1][t]] - h[f] Sin[γ[1][t] - θ[1][t] - ψ[1][t]] + 
   x[P1][t] == (-Cos[γ[2][t] - θ[2][t] - ψ[2][t]] l[f] + m[f] Sin[γ[2][t]] + 
   c[f] Sin[γ[2][t] - θ[2][t]] - h[f] Sin[γ[2][t] - θ[2][t] - ψ[2][t]] + 
   x[P2][t]) /. (γ[2][t] - θ[2][t] - ψ[2][t]) -> (γ[1][t] - θ[1][t] - ψ[1][t])
]
```

Comment: is it the "{", "}" which enable to make the replacement of a group of variables ?

Comment: it is  /. symbol in the answer that allows you to make the replacement.

Comment: i removed the "{" "}" because they were not necessary.